# Python to extract a paragraph from a text file: Split string with exact match of multiple nested delimiters

Tags: python, regex, string, text, split

I am reading hundreds of pdf files to extract the abstract. My strategy is:
(1) split after the delimiter `abstract`
(2) read abstract
(3) stop when blank line. 
Here is the code that can do this:

```
import re    
raw = ' Some text\n\nABSTRACT\nExtract \nthis text\n\nOther text'
pattern = 'abstract'
abstract = re.split(pattern ,raw, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1].split("\n\n")[0]
print(abstract)
```

The problem is that different pdf files would contain different forms for my delimiters such as `abstract:`,  `abstract:\n` , `abstract\n` , which are all nested. Accordingly I tried something like this:

```
    import re    
    raw = ' Some text\n\nAbstract:\n\nExtract \nthis text\n and include 
 abstraction and Abstraction \n\nOther text'
    pattern = 'abstract|abstract:|abstract:\n' 
    abstract = re.split(pattern, raw, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1].split("\n\n")[0]
    print(abstract)
```

Yet it did not work for the above example. Also, this code will not work for exact match. For example, it will not ignore `abstraction` and `Abstraction`

Comment: Is the double `\n` always present  before 'abstract' and after the expected text?

Comment: After 'abstract' there there could be anything like single \n, double \n or \t

Comment: Does you expected text contain new lines?

Comment: Yes. I changed the post accordingly.

Comment: Do you store the delimiters as a variable and build the pattern dynamically? How large can input string be?

Comment: I do not build the pattern dynamical, but rather I want exact match for the patter. From example, I want the code to exactly match `abstract` or `abstract:` and to ignore other words as `Abstraction` and `abstraction`. The input can be very long. It is the content of a pdf file with 5 to 20 pages of text. I changed the title of the post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

In the patterns you want to split on, have them ordered such if one is subset of another it comes later in the list

```
pattern = 'abstract:|abstract'
```

Don't worry about the trailing whitespace (`\n`, `\n\n`, `\n\t`) in the splitting, take care of that afterwards using `.strip()` as that will remove all kinds of whitespace from the ends of the string.

```
text_after_abstract_header = re.split(pattern, raw, flags=re.IGNORECASE)[1]
abstract = text_after_abstract_header.strip().split('\n\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add as much detail to the regexp as possible, in this case, we can add characters before and after `abstract`

```
>>> raw=' Some text\n\nABSTRACT:\t\nExtract this text\n adasdd\n\nSome other text'
>>> arr = re.split('(?i)\n{1,2}abstract[:\n\t]+',raw)[1].split('\n\n')
>>> arr
['Extract this text\n adasdd', 'Some other text']
>>> arr[0]
'Extract this text\n adasdd'
```

`(?i)` same as the `flags=re.IGNORECASE`
`\n{1,2}` 1 or 2 newlines
`[:\n\t]+` that list of characters 1 or more times.